# I have problem with optimization LCP in NextJS progect

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, next.js, lighthouse

Here is Lightouse warning about LCP after test(mobile) :
"Largest Contentful Paint element 4,900 ms". Load delay is 78%. I also have warning : "Preload Largest Contentful Paint image Potential savings of 460 ms". I am using preload for only for thouse images, which are firstly visible when page is loading. And i can expect exectly that thouse images has fetchpriority = "high" in html document. Help me please, what can i do in such case?

I use SSR, next/image with sizes and etc. I sliced big functions to small.Component with LCP is getting data from serverSideProps(i tryed even don't use useEffect to paste data as a state when componentDidMount to make data achieving by component even faster, but it didn't help) I also was expecting perfomance insights and found 1 long tasks. But this task is long mostly becouse of compiling code. I definitely do not understand why i have hight LCP. Help me pleaze

Comment: The LCP isn't necessarily about how optimized the image is. It can also be how and when you are loading it. Are you lazy loading the component with the image ?

Comment: No, i am not lazy loading the component with image. I have checked that

Comment: Then perhaps the image isn't the LCP of your application. It has to be something else

Comment: Lighthouse show exectly image which is LCP

Comment: Could you share a link to the page you're testing ?

Comment: @ninsau  I am sorry, it is privat for a while. The project has not been released yet. I realise that it is hard to give some advice when you can not see progect and can not test problem yourself. Maybe you can tell me if there is something that can block preloading images. Becouse i see warning "Preload Largest Contentful Paint image" while i am alredy doing it.